# Multiselect @Html.DropDownList would not drop in Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

MVC4,
In the partial view dropdown list does not drop down. What I am doing wrong?
Thank you

MyView.cshtml

```
 @Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialView1.cshtml", model);
```

MyPartialView1.cshtml

```
@model List<MyClass1>
@{
   SelectList list1 = MyHelper.GetList1();
   MultiSelectList mltpList= new MultiSelectList(lst1, "Value", "Text");
 }
............
<div>
    <label for="dd1">My Dropdown:</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("dd1", mltpList, null, new { multiple = "multiple", id = "dd1" })
</div>
```

Comment: if I remove   multiple="multiple"   it drops down. But I need dropdown that allows multiple selections. Please help.

Comment: You cant have both. `<select multiple>` allows mutliple selections but displays as a listbox where as `<select>` allows a single selection but displays as a dropdown. And creating a new SelectList (`mltpList`) from an existing SelectList (`list1`) is just pointless extra overhead. They are both `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which is what either `DropDownList()` or `ListBoxFor()` requires

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Html.ListBox` instead. Like this:

```
@Html.ListBox("dd1", mltpList, new { id = "dd1" })
```